# Search pattern and list filenames recursively

Tags: python-3.5

My below code is listing all the files irrespective of the pattern is matched or not. The file ss.txt doesn't contain the pattern but still getting the output

Added the code

```
import os
import re

files = []
pattern = re.compile('my')

for p, d, f in os.walk(r'C:\Users\anaveed\test'):
    for file in f:
        files.append(os.path.join(p, file))

for f in files:
    with open(f, 'r') as x:
        for i in x:
            Var1 = re.search(pattern, i)
        print(f)
        x.close()


C:\Users\anaveed\test\sample.txt
C:\Users\anaveed\test\testfile.txt
C:\Users\anaveed\test\hoax\a.txt
C:\Users\anaveed\test\hoax\ss.txt
```

Comment: Well, of course you are getting that output. Where you are checking the `Var1` ?

Comment: Sorry i didn't get you

Comment: You are assigning to variable `Var1` the result of `re.search()`. What will you do with this variable next?

Comment: I have modified the code to use variable Var1 but getting multiple filenames. Should re.search return only unique filename

Comment: With the updated code you are opening files and reading line by line from them and checking this line for the pattern. It seems that file `sample.txt` contains two lines with substring `my`. That's why you print it two times. Similar for other files.

Comment: That's my confusion. Can you provide me the solution?

Comment: Yes, the solution is to do regexp only on filename, not on contents of the file.

Comment: I tried without opening the file but now no output. Can you provide the code from your end

Comment: Maybe it's the right output? Does any of the filename in `C:\Users\anaveed\test` contain `my`?

Comment: C:\Users\anaveed\test\sample.txt --- Contains my
C:\Users\anaveed\test\testfile.txt --- Contains my
C:\Users\anaveed\test\hoax\a.txt --- Contains my
C:\Users\anaveed\test\hoax\ss.txt ---- Doesn't Contains my

Comment: The filenames you posted don't contain 'my' https://regex101.com/r/mlULB2/1 You need to be clear, do you want to search filename for the string or content of the file.

Comment: You didn't get my question. I want to search pattern inside files and then print those filenames. Out of 4 files, 3 files contains "my" pattern. Ideally, it should list only those 3 files

Comment: So the solution, where you were opening the files and searching line by line was quite ok. Just don't print the file for each find, only once. You can use `any()` in this case for example.

Comment: I m doing that only but don't know why is it printing ss.txt. This file doesn't contain "my" pattern

Comment: You are doing that with the code you just edited? As I said, you don't check the variable `Var1`, you just assign to it - that's the problem.

Comment: Can you edit the code and let me know ?

Comment: Yes, for example just assign `False` to `Var1` before the `for i in x`. Then in the loop if `re.search()` is `True` set `Var1` to `True` also. After the loop just check `Var1` and if it's `True` print the filename.

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
import re

files = []
pattern = re.compile('my')

for p, d, f in os.walk(r'C:\Users\anaveed\test'):
    for file in f:
        files.append(os.path.join(p, file))

for f in files:
    with open(f, 'r') as x:
        Var1 = False
        for i in x:
            if re.search(pattern, i):
                Var1 = True
        if Var1:
            print(f)
        x.close()

C:\Users\anaveed\test\sample.txt
C:\Users\anaveed\test\testfile.txt
C:\Users\anaveed\test\hoax\a.txt
```

Comment: One more thing, if you open file with `with`, you don't have to call `close()`, so you can remove this line. And consider using `any()` in this case.

Comment: Thanks a lot . Really appreciate your help